# Set view position to top right programmatically in cocoa touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I need to make sure that one view A (size: 200x200) is always aligned to top right corner inside second view B (full screen size). I want to make sure that view A stays in that place regardless of device orientation. Truth is I have no problem with this when using interface builder to position the views but I need to construct this programmatically. I suppose I should use some autoresizing settings, could you tell me which one is supposed to align the view to top right corner of its superview?

Comment: have you checked out the autoResizing property of UIView?http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAutoresizing

Comment: Is the autoresizingMask only property that is required for the behaviour I described? I tried different values of autoresizingMask property but to no avail...

Comment: You have to position the view at the correct position in the first place but then the re orientation during the rotation is done automatically by the resizing mask.

Comment: What position do you mean with "top right bottom". top and bottom at once what do you mean by that?

Comment: My mistake, it is "top right".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
UIView parentView  //your full screen view
UIView view //the 200x200 view

[parentView addSubview:view];
CGRect frame = view.frame;

//align on top right
CGFloat xPosition = CGRectGetWidth(parentView.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(frame);
frame.origin = CGPointMake(ceil(xPosition), 0.0);
view.frame = frame;

//autoresizing so it stays at top right (flexible left and flexible bottom margin)
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
```

That positions the view on top right and set's the autoresizing mask so it stays at that position.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me.  Just one modification to the last line above, that should be "view.autoresizingMask = ...".